# Flexbox, z-index & position: static: Why isn't it working?

Tags: html, css, z-index, flexbox

According to flexbox specification:

> ..4.3. Flex Item Z-Ordering ,... and `z-index` values other than
>   `auto` create a stacking context even if `position` is `static`.

So, I thought `z-index` / `opacity` is supposed to work as usual with flexbox but when I apply it to this HTML/CSS it doesn't work (my goal was to put `.header` on top of `.core` creating two layers):

```css
 .header {
   opacity: 0.5;
   z-index: 2;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-end;
 }
 .headerLeft {
   z-index: inherit;
   background-color: blue;
   text-align: right;
   align-self: stretch;
   flex: 2 1 250px;
 }
 .headerCenter {
   z-index: inherit;
   background-color: red;
   text-align: right;
   align-self: stretch;
   flex: 1 1 175px;
 }
 .headerRight {
   z-index: inherit;
   background-color: green;
   text-align: right;
   align-self: stretch;
   flex: 1 1 100px;
 }
 .core {
   z-index: 0;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-around;
 }
 .coreItem {
   align-self: stretch;
   flex: 1 1 400px;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerLeft">Left</div>
    <div class="headerCenter">Center</div>
    <div class="headerRight">Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="core">
    <div class="coreItem">Core1</div>
    <div class="coreItem">Core2</div>
    <div class="coreItem">Core3</div>
    <div class="coreItem">Core4</div>
    <div class="coreItem">Core5</div>
    <div class="coreItem">Core6</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I used proper prefixes on flex properties. I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like you wrote in your question, elements *do not* need to be positioned for `z-index` to work in a flex container.

Flex items can participate in a `z-index` stacking order even with `position: static`, which is not true for other CSS box models (except Grid) where `z-index` only works on positioned elements.

> [**4.3. Flex Item Z-Ordering**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting)
>
> Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks, except
>   that `order`-modified document order is used in place of raw document
>   order, and `z-index` values other than `auto` create a stacking context
>   even if `position` is `static`.

The reason `z-index` isn't working in your code is that `div.header` and `div.core` are not flex items. They are children of `body`, but `body` is not a flex container.

In order for `z-index` to work here, you'll need to apply `display: flex` to `body`.

Add this to your code:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbs728hs/42/)

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772825/3597276