# Using z-index to get div above another div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I want the `div1` to be above `div2`. I try with `z-index` but it does not work.

I've tried this code:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.div2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -15vh;
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `position: relative` to both divs and create [`stacking context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -15vh;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Or you could use [`transform-style: preserve-3d;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) so now `.div1` should be positioned in the **3D-space** and not  flattened in the plane.

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -15vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

You can also use some random [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) like `translate` or [`rotate`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/127/)

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(1px);
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(1px, -15vh);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

[`Filters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) also work but they have bad [`Support`](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter)

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  background: red;
  filter: brightness(0.4);
  z-index: 2;
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -15vh;
  filter: brightness(0.4);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

In many cases an element must be positioned for `z-index` to work.

Indeed, applying `position: relative` to the divs in the question would solve the `z-index` problem.

Actually, `position: fixed`, `position: absolute` and `position: sticky` will also enable `z-index`, but those values also change the layout. With `position: relative` the layout isn't disturbed.

Essentially, as long as the element isn't `position: static` (the default value) it is considered positioned and `z-index` will work.

---

Some answers here and in related questions assert that `z-index` works *only* on positioned elements. As of CSS3, this is no longer true.

Elements that are [***flex items***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) or [***grid items***](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) can use `z-index` even when `position` is `static`.

*From the specs:*

> [**4.3. Flex Item Z-Ordering**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting)
>
> Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks, except that order-modified document order is used in place of raw 
>   document order, and `z-index` values other than `auto` create a stacking context even if `position` is `static`.
>
> [**5.4. Z-axis Ordering: the `z-index` property**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order)
>
> The painting order of grid items is exactly the same as inline blocks, except that order-modified document order is 
>   used in place of raw document order, and `z-index` values other than `auto` create a stacking context even if 
>   `position` is `static`.

Here's a demonstration of `z-index` working on non-positioned flex items: https://jsfiddle.net/m0wddwxs/

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` only applies to elements with a `position` other than `static`, so for example: `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`.

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
}
.div1 {
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
}
.div2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -15vh;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default property for `div` is `position:static`, Add `position:relative` in both the `div` then only `z-index` will work.