# Stacking divs on top of each other

Tags: css, z-index, background-color, transparent

I have a very simple CSS question that I can't answer myself for some reason. I have a header that I'd like to add a black transparent background to it. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="directory">
 <div class="headerbg"></div>
 <h1>Rental Directory</h1>
</div>
```

The .headerbg has the black transparent background. But for some reason the H1 is layered underneath the black background. I tried z-indexing both the background or the h1 but I still can't get the H1 to stack on top of the background. Can someone please advise? Thank you.

Here is a link to the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1L2jxnx/1/

Comment: You're aware that z-index only works on positioned elements?

Comment: @CBroe, your comment is outdated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35772825/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` works for positioned `absolute` or `relative` elements, it's simple just add position relative and z-index for h1 tag,

```
h1 { font-size: 50px; border-bottom: 15px solid #e8cd54; position:relative; z-index:1 }
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1L2jxnx/4/)

Comment: Thank you @ocanal! I have used position relative like you advised. I totally forgot that z-index only works on positioned elements.

Comment: The list includes`fixed` as well; or to put it the other way around, z-index applies to any element that has a position different from the default `static`.

Comment: As of CSS3, elements do not necessarily need to be positioned for `z-index` to work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35772825/3597276

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue with your absolute positioning.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #e8cd54;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Replace the h1 with this code.

Comment: works, but why did you add `width` and `top` values? They are completely unnecessary.

Comment: For the yellow border to match your version, 100% the width.

Comment: Why do you think the author wants the border to be that long? I think it looked better before.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time. I totally forgot that z-index only works on positioned elements.

Answer (score 1):

z-index works fine for **absolute positioned elements**.

Or you may simply nest the h1 inside the headerbg.

```css
#directory { padding: 10px 0 10px 20px; position: relative; height: 35vh; background-image: url('https://markshimazuphotography.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/san_diego_skyline_coronado_sunset.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #fff;}
.headerbg { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width: 40em; height: 8em; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0; z-index:1}
h1 { position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;z-index:2;font-size: 50px; border-bottom: 15px solid #e8cd54; }
```

```html
<div id="directory">
  <div class="headerbg"></div>
  <h1>
  Rental Directory
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ali Sheikhpour I totally forgot z-index only works on positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're placing the H1 tags outside out side the headerbg div.
Try placing h1 inside the headerbg div like this:

```
<div class="headerbg">
<h1>Rental Directory</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.headerbg div` just for a background effect isn't the ideal way of coding the web.

I've removed the `.headerbg div` from the markup and added a `css pseudo element` to fix that issue. Like this.

```css
#directory { padding: 10px 0 10px 20px; position: relative; height: 35vh; background-image: url('https://markshimazuphotography.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/san_diego_skyline_coronado_sunset.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #fff;}
#directory::after {content: ''; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width: 40em; height: 8em; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0; }
h1 { position: absolute; font-size: 50px; border-bottom: 15px solid #e8cd54; z-index: 1}
```

```html
<div id="directory">
  <h1>
  Rental Directory
  </h1>
</div>
```

I've also added position in the `h1` element. Since the `parent div` is `position: relative` and the `pseudo element` is too I had to give the `h1` so as I could set `z-index: 1` to it as explained by @CBroe in your commments.