# CSS: Why is "z-index" not making one div appear on top of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

index and im having a problem. i have this button that when click, it will show to content but it does not overlap the div in front if it i have also tried to set its z-index on click here is my code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
    alert("Asd");
    $('#account-container').css('z-index', 11);
}
```

and here is what it looks like
[image]

any idea on what i should do? thanks so much

Comment: Content which is overlapped should have higher `z-index`

Comment: Try putting the `account-container` html after the current html. If I suppose your `account-container` is your popup.

Comment: check the z-index of the content div.. it might be higher than the signout widget. If not try setting z-index:-1 to the content widget

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code which produces the problem, or research "stacking context" a bit more. Zindex only positions elements behind/infront of elements in the __same stacking context__.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Higher `z-index` is not enough. Both elements must have `position` defined and it should be `absolute` and / or `relative`.

I would go with `relative` for parent and `absolute` for child (then also use `top` / `left` to position). Next play with `z-index` for both, where higher value is for the child (or the layer that must be on top).

**In most cases `z-index` should go together with `position` [but not always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772825/3597276).** Thanks to Michael_B for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Few pointers:

- `z-index` only works within a particular context i.e. `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute` position.
- `z-index` for a `relative` div has nothing to do with the `z-index` of an `absolute` or `fixed` div.
- `z-index` doesn't work on `static` positioned elements(there are exceptions in CSS3).

Comment: @AniMenon, Michael is right. Display flex does magic in CSS3.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Content which is overlapped must have higher `z-index`  value. can you put your code to jfiddle. so that I can help you

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below link. This should help you:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_zindex_div